# Symfony 3 validation groups inside child entity ignored

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a simple form, with two fields, email and name. email is in Accounts entity and name in child entity: MedicalCenters

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class AccountsMedicalCentersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'mapped' => false
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'validation_groups' => array('emailValidation','Default')
                )
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to validate the fields with validation groups because in the MedicalCenters entity I have some other validation, for other situations:

Accounts Entity, validation works fine:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"emailValidation"})
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"emailValidation"})
     *
     */
    protected $email;
 /**
     * @var \MedicalCenters
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MedicalCenters")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="medical_centers_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     *
     * @Assert\Valid
     *
     */
    private $medicalCenters;
```

MedicalCenters Entity, the validation groups are ignored and the error returned is the second one (address not blank):

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=300, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="name not blank", groups={"emailValidation"})
     *
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="address not blank")
     */
    private $address;
```

I don't understand why from the child entity is not validate only the name field, which belong to the group emailValidation? 
What am I doing wrong?

In the controller I have:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
                AccountsMedicalCentersType::class,
                $currentAccount,
                array(
                    'validation_groups' => array(
                        'emailValidation',
                        'Default'
                    )
                )
            );
```

Thanks

Comment: You must create a child form type for `email`. Then enable `'cascade_validation'    => true,`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option `cascade_validation` will do the trick, but that one is deprecated. Use the `Valid` constraint to validate sub objects. From the Symfony documentation:

> This constraint is used to enable validation on objects that are embedded as properties on an object being validated. This allows you to validate an object and all sub-objects associated with it. (source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;

class AccountsMedicalCentersType extends AbstractType
{
    ....

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('emailValidation','Default')
            'constraints' => array(
                new Valid()
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: This one helped me... 'constraints' => array(
                new Valid()
            )
Also we need to include "use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;" in the form type

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
```

for ur object whta u want to be validated too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).